# Finding dynamically created div

Tags: javascript, dom, firefox-addon

I want to change my dynamically created div
but i can't get this working
it's keep creating new divs

```
var div = document.getElementById('windowx');
var btn;
var doc = content.document

if (div)
{
  div = document.getElementById('windowx')
  div.innerHTML = "something new"
}
else
{
  doc = content.document
  div = doc.body.appendChild(doc.createElement("div"))
  div.setAttribute("id", "windowx")
  div.setAttribute("style",
    "position: fixed; top: 100px; left: 100px; width: 20em;"
    + "border: 2px outset orange; background-color: cornsilk;"
    )
  btn = div.appendChild(doc.createElement("button"))
  btn.setAttribute("style", "position: absolute; bottom: 1ex; right: 1ex;")
  btn.setAttribute("onclick", "document.body.removeChild(this.parentNode)")
  btn.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("Zamknij"))
}
```

Comment: Try `var div = content.document.getElementById('windowx');`. And why are you initializing variables multiple times with the same value?

Comment: Are you allergic to semicolons?

Comment: yes Firefox plugin:] adding content. helped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that it is clear that it is for a Firefox plugin:

`document.getElementById` will search for that element in the browser UI, not the web page. But later you are adding the element to the page. Therefore you have to search in the page for that element:

```
var div = content.document.getElementById('windowx');
```

Also, you are making some unnecessary method calls. Here is a cleaner version of your code:

```
var doc = content.document,
    div = doc.getElementById('windowx'),
    btn;

if (div) {
  div.innerHTML = "something new"
}
else {
  div = doc.body.appendChild(doc.createElement("div"))
  div.setAttribute("id", "windowx")
  div.setAttribute("style",
    "position: fixed; top: 100px; left: 100px; width: 20em;"
    + "border: 2px outset orange; background-color: cornsilk;"
    )
  btn = div.appendChild(doc.createElement("button"))
  btn.setAttribute("style", "position: absolute; bottom: 1ex; right: 1ex;")
  btn.setAttribute("onclick", "document.body.removeChild(this.parentNode)")
  btn.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("Zamknij"))
}
```

Comment: i have another simple question;p is there a easy way to create div in cursor position ? i mean something like   div.setAttribute("style",
    "position: fixed; top: mouseX; left: mouseY; width: 20em;"
    + "border: 2px outset orange; background-color: cornsilk;"
    )
?

Comment: The position should be `absolute` I guess, and yes, you can do this if you have the coordinates...

Answer (score 0):

For me it was choking on `content.document`, the window object doesn't have a content property so I'm not sure what you were referencing.  Cleaned up a bit and it seems to work.  Note I'm adding the click handler directly instead of setting it as an attribute.  See here where I have it triggered by a jQuery button click handler: http://jsfiddle.net/hN8uz/1/

```
var doc = document;
var div = doc.getElementById('windowx');
var btn;

if (div) {
    div.innerHTML = "something new";
}
else {
    div = doc.body.appendChild(doc.createElement("div"));
    div.setAttribute("id", "windowx");
    div.setAttribute("style", "position: fixed; top: 100px; left: 100px; width: 20em;" + "border: 2px outset orange; background-color: cornsilk;");
    btn = div.appendChild(doc.createElement("button"));
    btn.setAttribute("style", "position: absolute; bottom: 1ex; right: 1ex;");
    btn.onclick = function() {
        document.body.removeChild(this.parentNode);
    };
    btn.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("Zamknij"));
}
```

Comment: It could be be that this in the context of a Firefox plugin... at least that's what I assumed.

Comment: I suppose that it might work in FF, but I'm using Safari.  Didn't try it in FF and it's not clear that the OP is using FF either.